# Convert Decimal to Time Output in SQL - Teradata

Tags: sql, time, format, teradata

I am querying via Teradata SQL Assistant and have a field (DECSN_TIME) that outputs as an integar with length between 1 and 6.

I would like to format the integar into a time format (HH:MM:SS)

Example of Output : 1 should be 00:00:01 .... 
                   45 should be 00:00:45 ....
               152251 should be 15:22:51 or 03:22:51 PM

Answer (score 3):

Format like a `TIME`, i.e. result is a string:

```
CAST((DECSN_TIME (FORMAT '99:99:99')) AS CHAR(8))
```

Actually return a `TIME`:

```
CAST(CAST((DECSN_TIME (FORMAT '99:99:99')) AS CHAR(8)) AS TIME(0))
```

Comment: Teradata keeps returning an error for Illegal Symbol ('99:99:99')- I've tried different variations (removing the ' ' or putting HH:MM:SS) and all return the same error.  @dnoeth

Comment: @MarcusMonn: What's the exact datatype & the exact SQL? What's the exact error, 3530 Invalid FORMAT?

Comment: select app_num, dt_entered, time_appl_entered, decsn_dt,  status_field,CAST(CAST((DECSN_TIME (FORMAT '99:99:99')) AS CHAR(8)) AS TIME(0))
from adm_app_info
where dt_entered between '2016-01-01' and '2016-01-31'


...........SELECT Failed. 104: DSNT408I SQLCODE = -104, ERROR:  ILLEGAL SYMBOL "'99:99:99'". SOME SYMBOLS THAT MIGHT BE LEGAL ARE: CONCAT || / MICROSECONDS MICROSECOND SECONDS SECOND MINUTES  @dnoeth

Comment: @MarcusMonn: `SELECT 123456 AS DECSN_TIME, CAST(CAST((DECSN_TIME (FORMAT '99:99:99')) AS CHAR(8)) AS TIME(0))` works fine for me. What's the datatype of `DECSN_TIME`

Comment: DECIMAL(6.0), Not Null   @dnoeth - thank you for your assistance and time

Comment: @MarcusMonn: Strange, this should also work with a DECIMAL. Do you use ODBC to connect? Check if the second character of `DateTime Format` in the ODBC driver options is not set to 'I', change to 'A'. Or check the `Disable Parsing`